# Inequality of exponential function

Tags: analysis, inequality

I want to prove that $$ e^x>x^e$$ (if it's true), without grafic methods, using some algebraic inequality.

Thanks.

Comment: Which values of $x$ are you trying to prove this for? It's not true for all $x$. For example, $x=e$ gives $e^e = e^e$.

Comment: @John11 That's a sufficiently different question, I think

Answer (score 1):

taking the natural logarithm of both sides we obtain:
$$x\ln(e)>e\ln(x)$$ and this is equivalent to
$$x>e\ln(x)$$ if $$0<x<1$$ you will get the inequality $$\frac{x}{\ln(x)}<e$$
and this is true since $$\ln(x)<0$$
$$x=1$$ can be then we will get $$e>1$$ which is true.
if $$x>1$$ then we have the inequality $$\frac{x}{\ln(x)}>e$$ 
the last inequality is true for $$1<x<e$$ or $$x>e$$